# Adobe brackets installer error code 2755

Tags: out-of-memory, text-editor, brackets, adobe-brackets

when i want to install brackets on my win 10, it shown me this error message:

[image]

please help me

Comment: Please put MSI log files for one to help trobuleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to make sure the directory 'c://Windows/Installer' is existed,
if the directory is not existed, create it and try reinstall.  If this problem still occurs, please run the command "msiexec /i your_bracket.msi /L*V 1.log",then you can find error message in '1.log'.